# Showing image with Picasso custom Downloaded uses a lot of memory

Tags: android, picasso, expansion

I'm trying to populate the RecyclerView item with an image loaded by a custom Picasso Downloader and I noticed that the application is using way to much memory and the scrolling is not smooth. The images are loaded from an obb expansion zip file. Here is my custom downloaded:

```
public class VirtualTourDownloader implements Downloader {

    private final ZipResourceFile mZipResourceFile;
    private InputStream mInputStream;

    public VirtualTourDownloader(ZipResourceFile zipResourceFile) {
        mZipResourceFile = zipResourceFile;
    }

    @Override
    public Response load(Uri uri, int networkPolicy) throws IOException {
        String path = uri.getPath();
        String idStr = "virtual/" + path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        mInputStream = mZipResourceFile.getInputStream(idStr);
        return new Response(mInputStream, false, mInputStream.available());
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        try {
            mInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Picasso with custom downloader

init inside the adapter

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(mContext).downloader(new VirtualTourDownloader(expansionFile));
mPicasso = builder.build();
```

onBind load the image into ImageView

```
mPicasso.load(uri).into(image);
```

Comment: can you resize the and then check your scrolling using resize method like :
mPicasso.load(uri).resize(200,200).centerCrop().into(image);

Comment: Vivek, thanks for you reply. Resizing the image solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Glide library.

**Benefits are:**
1.  it will consume less memory.
2. Glide’s default bitmap format is set to RGB_565 so image quality will be poorer compared with Picasso.

3.Glide creates cached images per size while Picasso saves the full image and process it. Means If you are trying to load image(500 x 500) into imageView (200 x 200). Glide will download full image, then resize it to 200 x 200, then it will cache and load into imageView while Picasso will download full image then it will cache full image then resize it to 200 x 200 and load it into imageView.

Next time when you request same image(500 x 500) to load into imageView(100 x 100) , Glide will again download the full image(500 x 500) then resize it to 100 x 100 then cache and load into imageView. Picasso, unlike Glide, picks up the cached full size image and resize and load it into imageView(100 x 100). Picasso doesn’t download same image again.

this content is taken from(http://tutorialwing.com/android-glide-library-tutorial-example/)

For using Glide  add this dependencies in your Gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```